Fresh ubuntu repeatedly ask to reboot
i got a fresh ubuntu 24.04 install on a Lenovo X13 G3 AMD
on the install everything went fine,
no issues with the laptop everything works : wifi, graphic, fingerprint reader, ...
after a day or to and "sometimes" ubuntu show the popup like this one

when i push "cancel" it shows up every few seconds.... i have to suspend or restart to make it stop.
I have no idea why, any idea how i can start investigating? like who is starting
this?
EDIT:
i found via dbus that it seems to be a media key press?

if i try to listen for event
i get

Event: time 1718215968.052886, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 116 (KEY_POWER), value 1
Event: time 1718215968.052886, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1718215968.052905, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 116 (KEY_POWER), value 0
Event: time 1718215968.052905, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------

maybe i ca remap that or something?

Have you enabled unattended upgrade or automatic security upgrades? If so, how? If you used the terminal or modified any files, then copy and paste those commands, and content of the files directly in your question and format them as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

When you see this message, press Cancel and open a terminal. Enter the command cat /var/run/reboot-required and copy and paste the content in your question.

There is no /var/run/reboot-required

If it is unrelated to "unattended upgrade" I am out of ideas.

thanks :) i've update the question, i got more info, maybe it helps?

That sounds like a hardware problem. Try remapping the key.

how can i do that?
(you mean hardware compatibilty or hardware issue?)

I don't know how to remap the key, or which key to remap. I meant faulty hardware, but it could be compatibility, though I think the probability is low.
